# Close pop-up then go to a URL in the parent

Tags: javascript

I've opened a popup with:

```
window.open(url, 'mySurvey', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,dependent,width=1000, height=800,left=50,top=50');
```

When that window is open the user can click a link that will close the window, then redirect to a page in the parent window.

I'm familiar with `window.close()` and that works OK. I'm unsure how to get a redirect action in the parent window with the same click action.

Comment: [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the window that opened the popup using `window.opener` or `window.parent`. You can use that in your click event before closing the popup:

```
function myClickEvent(){
    window.opener.location.href = "the_new_url.htm";
    //or window.parent.location.href = "the_new_url.htm";
    window.close();
}
```